# How do you display a variable in a kv file

Tags: python, kivy

Here is the py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
import string
import random


class MyGrid(Widget):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    bmi = NumericProperty(0)

    def btn(self):
        height = float(self.name.text)
        weight = float(self.email.text)
        bmi = weight/(height*height)
        
        print("Name:", self.name.text, "email:", self.email.text, "bmi:", str(bmi))
        self.name.text = ""
        self.email.text = ""
        show_popup()

class P(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

def show_popup():
    show = P()

    popupWindow = Popup(title="BMI", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))

    popupWindow.open()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Here is the kv file

```
<MyGrid>:

    name: name
    email: email

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Height: "

            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Weight: "

            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline:False

        Button:
            text:"Submit"
            on_release: root.btn()

<P>:
    Label:
        text: "Your BMI is: "
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}
```

How do you display the value of the variable 'BMI' in the label. I want the popup message to show the following text: "Your BMI is: " + bmi but when I do that it gives an error. How do you display an variable in a kv file. This is a very simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Do you just say text: "Your BMI is: " + root.bmi because I have tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to just pass the BMI into the `show()` method. Here is a modified `show()` method that does that:

```
def show_popup(bmi):
    show = P()

    popupWindow = Popup(title="BMI", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    show.ids.bmi.text = "Your BMI is: " + str(bmi)

    popupWindow.open()
```

The above requires an `id` in the `kv`:

```
<P>:
    Label:
        id: bmi
        text: "Your BMI is: "
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}
```

And a slight modification to the `btn()` method to pass the BMI value:

```
def btn(self):
    height = float(self.name.text)
    weight = float(self.email.text)
    bmi = weight / (height * height)

    print("Name:", self.name.text, "email:", self.email.text, "bmi:", str(bmi))
    self.name.text = ""
    self.email.text = ""
    show_popup(bmi)
```